# google visualization formatter - no table values

Tags: google-visualization, formatter

I have a google.visualization Datatable that shows up correcty with the values handed over by the data source

But if I try to add a formatter to the datatable then it fails and does not show the datatable

This is the Format of the Data in "dataTable"

**dataTable**=Object { cols=[2], rows=[2]}

**cols**
    [Object { type="string", id="Description", label="Description"}, Object { type="number", id="1", label="1"}]

0   Object { type="string", id="Description", label="Description"}

1   Object { type="number", id="1", label="1"}

**rows**
    [Object { c=[2] }]

0 Object { v=59.38}

1 Object { v=19.12}

**This Table is correctly shown like follows:**

Description  |   1

---

First Value  |  59.38

Second Value |  19.12

**This is the code I use and that produces above result ...**

```
       var dtWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: "Table",
            dataTable: dataTable,
            options: {width: tableWidth},
            containerId: tableHolder
        });

        // here the formatter will be inserted (before .draw)

        dtWrapper.draw();
```

**If I insert the following formatter code it throws an Error in the console:**

```
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
              {prefix: "Value: "});
        formatter.format(dataTable, 1); // Apply formatter to second column
```

**This is the Error Message I am seeing in the firebug- console:**

TypeError: a[da] is not a function

...is.N?K:t(this.N))&&0>d&&ala}}});$[H].formatValue=function...

http://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/4086f2e8fc632adc52e6d6795a5637a4/format+de,default,controls,corechart.I.js

Line 56

**Here is the Data that is handed over by my ashx-handler:**

```
dataTable =  
{
"cols": 
  [
     {"type": "string" , "id": "Timerange" ,"label": "Timerange"},
     {"type": "number" ,"id": " 2013" ,"label": " 2013" }
  ], 
"rows" :
   [
     {"c" : [
              {"v": "< 15"}, {"v": 0}
            ]
     },
     {"c" : [
              {"v": "16 - 20"}, {"v": 15.63}
            ]
     }, 
     {"c" : [
               {"v": "21 - n"}, {"v": 15.63}
            ]
     },
     {"c" : [
              {"v": "> n"}, {"v": 68.75}
            ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Please can anybody assist how to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance for any guidance
Don

Answer (score 2):

If `dataTable` only contains "cols" and "rows" properties, then it is not a proper DataTable object.  At a guess, `dataTable` is something like this:

```
var dataTable = {
    cols: [
        {type: 'string', id: 'Description', label: 'Description'},
        {type: 'number', id: '1', label: '1'}
    ],
    rows: [
        {c: [{v: 'First Value'}, {v: 59.38}]},
        {c: [{v: 'Second Value'}, {v: 19.12}]}
    ]
};
```

right?  If so, then you need to pass it to a DataTable constructor:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataTable);
```

You can then format and draw your table with `data`.

Edit:

Here's an example fiddle that shows how to make this work: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/vT4Re/

Comment: Thanks very much for reponding to my question, the table is shown normal with the code above. This is some Sample Data coming from my ashx-Handler that provides the data for the datatable and also for charts on the page: {"cols": [{"type": "string" ,"id": "Timerange" ,"label": "Timerange" }, {"type": "number" ,"id": "  2013" ,"label": "  2013" }], "rows" : [{"c" : [{"v": "< 15"}, {"v": 0}]}, {"c" : [{"v": "16 - 20"}, {"v": 15.63}]}, {"c" : [{"v": "21 - n"}, {"v": 15.63}]}, {"c" : [{"v": "> n"}, {"v": 68.75}]}]}  As mentioned charts&tables are propagated correct until i try to format the values

Comment: You need to put it in a DataTable constructor, as I said in my post.  When you assign an object like that to the ChartWrapper's "dataTable" parameter, the wrapper internally converts it into a DataTable object so it can use the data, which is why your charts and tables work, but since your object isn't a DataTable, the formatting functions won't work on it.

Comment: Asgallant - you have saved my week - sorry that I didnt get it on your first reply - the word "DataTable" did irritate me - but your fiddle-example made it absolutely clear to me! I would have voted you up to 10,000 ;-) but I can´t because of my actual "reputation" ... So all I can do is to say: Thanks a lot for your patience and help!